# How do i unset duplicate string in a str_split string line

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, unset

How do i check if same string occurs twice or multiples times and remove it. Example the split string is **123 456 123 789**, I want to be able to unset the repeated character in the split string line 
example my expected output should be like **web123 web456 web789**. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php

$str = "jmja12345jmja612378911";
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$disp = str_split($int, 3);
foreach($disp as $char){
    if(strlen($char) == "3") 
    {
        $net = substr($char,1,2);
        if(preg_match('/(50|30)/i', $net))
        {
            echo "our computer can not edit $net";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            $pd = str_replace("$net","web$net",$net);
            $str = implode(array_unique(explode( $pd)));
            echo $str;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get no good result. What am I doing wrong? view at https://ideone.com/fork/rGyH41

Comment: What's the expected output? The input with the repeated number removed or just the numbers?

Comment: You don't use `explode()` correctly. It expects two Parameters: `explode(string $delimiter, string $inputString)`.

Comment: I don't get the question. `array_unique` and `implode` should be enough to get the expected result. Check it out: [https://eval.in/916637](https://eval.in/916637)

Comment: @Tobia F. 
I do not get your idea please give a code edition of your soluction in answer

Comment: @KingsleyPlaza take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and your following line of Code: `explode( $pd);`

Comment: @FirstOne I want it just as in the stage not looking at the example should be 
web123 web456 web789
belive you get my question clear now

Comment: @KingsleyPlaza : the explode function in this part ($str = implode(array_unique(explode( $pd)));) is wrong. Explode function needs another parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just need to remove the duplicate values . why you not try it directly like this .

```
<?php

$str = "jmja12345jmja612378911";
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$disp = str_split($int, 3);
$arr = array_unique($disp);
var_dump($arr);
```

and for your function to work . try this

```
$str = "jmja12345jmja612378911";
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$disp = str_split($int, 3);
foreach($disp as $char){
    if(strlen($char) == "3") 
    {
        $net = substr($char,1,2);
        if(preg_match('/(50|30)/i', $net))
        {
            echo "our computer can not edit $net";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            $pd[] = str_replace("$net","web$net",$net);
        }
    }
}

$array = array_values(array_unique($pd));
var_dump($array);
$str = implode(array_unique($pd));
echo $str;
```

Comment: I dont really no how to explain my question but looking at my code above the output for echo ($pd); is like web23 web 56 web23 web89
now i want my soluction on ($pd) variable  so i could have just web23 web 56 web89 belive you understand now  or see here https://ideone.com/Fa6VI0

Comment: @KingsleyPlaza . check the updates now . it should suits what you need .

Comment: Yes thanks alot but i want to be able to detect (IF string is duplicated before action example

if(duplicate string in line)
{
$str = implode(array_unique($pd));

 }
else
{
$str = "$pd";
}

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to remove all non numeric characters from your string and get an array that doesn't repeat the numeric values.
Here is a simple way to do it.

```
$str = "jmja12345jmja612378911";
$onlyNumbers = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $str);

$array = str_split($onlyNumbers,3);
$arrayWithoutRepetition = array_unique($array);
print_r($arrayWithoutRepetition);
```

I hope this solves your problem.